# Project to new class from two linq lists

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have an existing class that, paired down, looks like this:

```
public class SiloNode
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<string> RelatedTopics { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

**Key**, is a unique key, while **RelatedTopics** contains a list of Keys that are related.

I maintain a list of these nodes:

```
List<SiloNode> MasterList = new List<SiloNode>();
```

I use a query to extract all the related topics then create some links later:

```
public static IEnumerable<SiloNode> RelatedNodes(this SiloNode root)
{
    return MasterList.Where(x => root.RelatedTopics.Contains(x.Key));
}
```

**All of the above works.**

However, I need to change **RelatedTopics** so that I can add some anchor text that is unique to the relationship.

So, first, I created two more classes:

```
public class RelatedNode
{
    public string AnchorText { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class NodeLink
{
    public NodeLink(string url, string text)
    {
        Url = url;
        Text = text;
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Then I make changes to my SiloNode class:

```
public class SiloNode
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<RelatedNode> RelatedTopics { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

So now, instead of **RelatedTopics** just containing a simple key, it also contains some anchor text that I would like to apply to that relationship.

Here's the bit where I'm struggling - **the code below is incomplete**:

```
public static IEnumerable<NodeLink> RelatedNodes(this SiloNode root)
{
    return MasterList.Where(x => root.RelatedTopics.Contains(x.Key))
        .Select(y => new NodeLink(y.Url, "HOW DO I GET ANCHOR TEXT?"));
}
```

**I need to link the two sides together in such a way that I can access y.Url and root.RelatedTopics.Text.**

I still need to match the related nodes but then project to a new NodeLink. While the key is available in 'x', the anchor text is in root.RelatedTopics. I assume that the current linq structure is insufficient to resolve this query but I'm no expert.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is `Silos.LoanSilo`? That still seems to contain `RelatedTopics` as a list of strings, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: Sorry, code copying error.

Comment: That still seems to contain RelatedTopics as a list of strings - that's where I'm stuck Gert, I don't know what to replace the contains with.

Comment: @JohnOhara, did my answer help you solve your issue? If so, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and I'll try to help further.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `Contains` with `Any`, and add an inner `Select`:

```
masterList
 .Where(m => m.RelatedTopics.Any(t => m.Key == t.Key))
 .Select(m => m.RelatedTopics.Where(m.Key == t.Key)
                             .Select(t => new NodeLink(m.Url, t.AnchorText)));
```

Alternatively, do as follows:

```
masterList
 .Select(m => m.RelatedTopics
                 .Where(t => m.Key == t.Key)
                 .Select(t => new NodeLink(m.Url, t.AnchorText)));
```